# Код запускается отдельно от виртуального окружения

Tags: python, telebot

Запускаю команду import telebot и выдает ошибку[image: на изображении я активировал виртуальное окружение в файле, но ошибка повторяетсяи виртуальное окружение не сохраняется, приходится заново активировать постоянно]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Ну так вы сами и сказали ему запускаться отдельно от виртуального окружения: написали `C:/Users/.../python.exe`. Указывайте путь к интерпретатору внутри venv'а.